# Visual Studio 2019 Professional: SSDT Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12 target platform is missing

Tags: visual-studio, azure, sql-server-data-tools

I installed the latest Visual Studio Professional 2019. I have an old database project. After the Visual Studio update, the 'Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12' option of target platform in the database properties page is missing. So I can't compile and publish my project to my existing Azure SQL database. Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Here is my Visual Studio 2019 version information:

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.4.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.4.3+29709.97
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.03752

Installed Version: Professional

## ProductName   1.6.16

## ProductDescription

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.4.457.38025
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.4.457.38025
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.4.457.38025
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Node   1.0
This package contains the Data Lake integration nodes for Server Explorer.

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.1000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.4.457.38025
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.4.1000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   3.4.1-beta4-19610-02+c4e5d138903b899477649a17f197abd2bcb22f9e
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

IntelliCode Extension   1.0
IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Markdown Editor   1.12.253
A full featured Markdown editor with live preview and syntax highlighting. Supports GitHub flavored Markdown.

Microsoft Azure HDInsight Azure Node   2.4.1000.0
HDInsight Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.4.1000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   16.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.4.1000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Node   1.0
Azure Stream Analytics Node under Azure Node

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 - v2.9.21016.1

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.0.87+gbb515bf382
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

NuGet Package Manager   5.4.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

PowerShell Pro Tools for Visual Studio   1.0
A set of tools for developing and debugging PowerShell scripts and modules in Visual Studio.

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.61912.09160
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   16.0.11031.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.4.1-beta4-19610-02+c4e5d138903b899477649a17f197abd2bcb22f9e
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6   16.4.0-beta.19556.5+e7597deb7042710a7142bdccabd6f92b0840d354
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.4 for F# 4.6

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions (Preview)   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Kubernetes

VsVim   2.8.0.0
VsVim is a Vim emulator for Visual Studio

Comment: I have it neither. I guess it's simply because V12 is the standard now and pre-V12 isn't supported anymore. So just switch to the available Azure-Profile and re-compile.

Comment: I tried to use the option "Microsoft Azure SQL Database", but got compile errors. I tried to use "SQL Server 2017" or "SQL Server 2019 or Azure SQL Database Managed Instance", but I can't publish to Azure SQL Database. I had to go back to use Visual Studio 2017 to continue my work.